# ReactJS Failed to Compile Syntax Error Unexpected token; common problem but I can't solve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

MacOSX
Node:v15.10.0
NPM: 7.5.3

I realize this is a common problem and I've been trying to resolve this for over a day and after trying a bunch of different solutions, I have not been able to resolve this. I'm learning ReactJS and following along guides that start off with create-react-app. Regardless of the guide, I'm getting the following:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/requests.js
SyntaxError: /Users/.../requests.js: Unexpected token (4:22)
```

I have tried to resolve Webpack and Babel discrepancies through package.json, webpack.config.js and .babelrc, but nothing seems to work. I tried deleting node-modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling everything in the app. I have tried not having the webpack.config file and half a dozen variations of presets, excludes, etc. I also tried completely reinstalling node and npm, but still no dice.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Row from "./Row.js";
import requests from "./requests.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
          Starting NetFlavor
      </div>
      <Row title="Weekly Trending" fetchURL={requests.fetchWeekTrending} />
      <Row title="Newest" fetchURL={requests.fetchMovie}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

requests.js

```
const API_KEY = '';

const requests = {
    fetchWeekTrending = '/trending/movie/week?api_key=${API_KEY}',
    fetchMovie = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/228203?api_key==${API_KEY}'
};

export default requests;
```

Row.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Row({ title }) {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'chamber.js'
    },
    
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options:{
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    '@babel/preset-react'
                ],
            }
            }}
        ]},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/index.html'
        })
    ],
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "chamber",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ]
}
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Would appreciate any help. At this point I can't even learn just because I can't get past this error.

Comment: can you share the error details more precisely?

Comment: You posted the error message and your build config, but you didn't post the actual code that's throwing the error. Please show the actual code that's causing the issue

Comment: `SyntaxError: /Users/...js: Unexpected token (4:22)` Did you replace the file name with `...`? This error message tells you where the problem is. Line 4, column 22 in that file has a syntax error.

Comment: @Håken Lid Yes! I updated my post. Sorry, I edited the post with the actual code. It does seem to occur when calling instances from modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you have a syntax error in your requests.js.
Note the `const requests`: use `:` to assign properties and use backticks.

```
const API_KEY = '';

const requests = {
    fetchWeekTrending: `/trending/movie/week?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
    fetchMovie: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/228203?api_key==${API_KEY}`
};

export default requests;
```